# Usage of "with" and "in"

Tags: word-usage

**Are we really living with a developed economy?** 
Please tell if the usage of with is appropriate. Would it be correct to write it like: 
"Are we really living **in** a developed economy?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! Please **include the [research](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/5039/how-much-research-is-needed)** you've done, or consider if your question suits our [ell.se] site better. Questions that can be answered using [commonly-available references](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available) are off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

"Are we really living in a developed economy?" is more correct.

"Are we really living with a developed economy?" is technically appropriate, but the preposition "with" translates to "alongside," evoking a confusing separation between the subject "we" and the direct object "economy." If you use the first sentence, your reader will likely question whether or not you belong to the economy you are discussing.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, "to live with" is used to describe putting up with something, or used more literally to describe living alongside something.

> I have to live with incessant incompetency.
>
> I live with my flatmates.

It would only be appropriate to say your sentence using "live with" if you meant that you meant the same as "are we really putting up with a developed economy". Otherwise "living in" is the correct term, assuming you're questioning the nature of the economy in which you live.